# Solve the equation $x=[2;2,2,\ldots,2,2,x]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, continued-fractions

Solve the equation

$x=[2;2,2,\ldots,2,2,x]$

where there are n layers of continued fractions.

Can someone start off the solution for me? I think it may be using induction.

Comment: Euler's formula for evaluating a continued fraction. Use induction on n.

Answer (score 4):

For starters,
$$ [\underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2,2}_{m\text{ times}}]=\frac{P_{m+1}}{P_m}\tag{1} $$
where $P_m=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^m-(1-\sqrt{2})^m}{2\sqrt{2}}$ is a [Pell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number). It follows that the equation
$$ x=[\underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2,2}_{m\text{ times}},x]\tag{2} $$
is equivalent to:
$$ x = \frac{P_m+ P_{m+1} x}{P_{m-1}+P_m x}\tag{3} $$
and always has the same solutions for every $m\geq 1$: they are $\color{red}{1\pm\sqrt{2}}$.

---

**Later rework**. Let us do this step-by-step. First claim: the (Pell) numbers defined through $P_m = \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^m-(1-\sqrt{2})^m}{2\sqrt{2}}$ are integers fulfilling the constraints $P_0=0, P_1=1$ and $P_{m+2}=2\,P_{m+1}+P_m$. The proof by induction is straightforward. Second claim:
$$ R_m= [\underbrace{2;2,\ldots,2}_{m\text{ times}}] = \frac{P_{m+1}}{P_m}.$$
Here we have $R_{m+1}=2+\frac{1}{R_m}$, hence a proof by induction is straightforward in this case, too.
The identity
$$ [\underbrace{2;2,\ldots,2}_{m\text{ times}},x] = \frac{P_m+P_{m+1}x}{P_{m-1}+P_m x} $$
then follows from the general theory of continued fractions: in order to have an explicit expression for $[a;b,c,d,x]$ it is enough to know $[a;b,c,d]$ and the previous convergent $[a;b,c]$. At last, to check
$$ \forall x\in\{1-\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt{2}\},\;\forall m\geq 1\qquad x=\frac{P_m+P_{m+1}x}{P_{m-1}+P_m x}$$
is just a matter of substituting the right things and simplifying.

Comment: There are n layers altogether so shouldn't it be n-1 times?

Comment: @KanosHulai: in such a case my $n$ is OP's $n$ minus one, but that does not affect the final outcome.

Comment: Why would the solution be that ? I do not understand

Comment: @KanosHulai: if you know how to express $[a,b,c,d,x]$ given $[a,b,c]$ and $[a,b,c,d]$ and you know the closed form for Pell numbers, you may easily check that $1\pm\sqrt{2}$ always are solutions of $(3)$. On the other hand, $(3)$ cannot have more than two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $$x^{2}-2x-1=0\tag{1}$$ then $$x=2+\frac{1}{x}$$ but now we can replace $x$ in the denominator by $2+\frac{1}{x}$ so $$x=2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}\tag{2}$$ and so on $$x=2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dots1/x}}\tag{3}$$ and obviously the solutions of $(1)$, hence of $(2)$ hence of $(3)$ are always $$x=\color{red}{1\pm\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: could you show in more detail how the solutions of 2 and 3 are equal to that please

Comment: @KanosHulai We have $x=2+\frac{1}{x}$ so $x$ and $2+\frac{1}{x}$ are equal. Then replace $x$ in the denominator by $2+\frac{1}{x}$. So we have $(2)$ now. Again replace the denominator $x$ with $2+\frac{1}{x}$ and go on.